# Javascript output of module explanation

Tags: javascript, module

Can someone please explain me why the JS output is "1 2 1 3" and not "1 2 3"?

I have used JS module.

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/g6mJq/

I just want to know why the module is called is twice and where exactly in the code it happens?

Code:

```
(function() {
  var foo = function(arg) { // core constructor
    // ensure to use the `new` operator

    console.log("1");
    if (!(this instanceof foo))
    {
      console.log("2");
      return new foo(arg);
    }

    // store an argument for this example
    console.log("3");
    this.myArg = arg;
    //..
  };

  // create `fn` alias to `prototype` property
  foo.fn = foo.prototype = {

    init: function () {/*...*/
    }
    //...
  };

  // expose the library
  console.log("4");
  window.foo = foo;
  console.log("5");
})();

// Extension:

foo.fn.myPlugin = function () {
  console.log(this.myArg);
  return this; // return `this` for chainability
};
console.log("7");
foo("bar").myPlugin(); // alerts "bar"
```

Comment: `return new foo(arg);` returns from the function and calls it again as a constructor. My guess is that you'd want `return new foo.fn.init(arg)` - though then you'd have to rework the instanceof checking as well.

Comment: Is the fiddle URL correct seems to point to wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone please explain me why the JS output is "1 2 1 3" and not "1 2 3"?

Because this call to `foo`:

```
foo("bar").myPlugin();
```

...calls `foo` without using `new`, and so `this instanceof foo` just before `console.log("2")` is false (because `this` is either the global object or `undefined`, depending on whether you're using loose or strict mode), and so the function calls itself via `new` and returns the result rather than running the rest of its code directly. (This is a pattern used to make it possible to use the function both with and without `new` and get the result as though `new` had been used; in this case, `foo` is ensuring that the rest of its code [in the second call] is working with `this` referring to an object that is backed by `foo.prototype` [which has been aliased as `foo.fn`].)

> ...and where exactly in the code it happens?

The first call is the one I quoted above, which is very near the bottom of the code in the question. The second one is inside `foo` near the top:

```
return new foo(arg);
```

`new foo` does this:

1. Create a new object.
2. Set the new object's prototype to the object referenced by `foo.prototype`.
3. Call `foo` with `this` referencing the new object.